# When extending an abstract class by another abstract class how do you deal with constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract

I have a class named Event, it's abstract. I have another class named RecurringEvent that is also abstract and extends Event. Event compiles but RecurringEvent does not with the error.

Error:

```
RecurringEvent.java:6: error: constructor Event in class Event cannot be applied to given types;  
    {  
    ^  
  required: int  
  found: no arguments  
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Code:

```
public abstract class Event implements Comparable 
{
private int timeAtWhichEventHappens;

public Event(int t)
{

    setTime(t);
}

public abstract void execute(Simulator s);

public int getTime()
{
    return timeAtWhichEventHappens;
}

public void setTime(int t)
{
    timeAtWhichEventHappens = t;
}

public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    Event e = (Event) o;

    return e.getTime()-getTime();

}

}


public abstract class RecurringEvent extends Event
{
private int period;

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The code the error message is coming from clearly doesn't match the code you've posted; the error message says `public class RecurringEvent` instead of `public abstract class RecurringEvent`. You may be looking at the wrong code.

Comment: Yeah you were right, i tried out a few things and posted the wrong error. here is the right error .  RecurringEvent.java:6: error: constructor Event in class Event cannot be applied to given types;  
 {  
 ^   
  required: int   
  found: no arguments  
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length .          This is formatted much better in the edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor `Event(int)` requires an integer parameter.

*Ergo* your `RecurringEvent` constructor must call `super(int)`, which it isn't, as you haven't declared it at all, and the compiler isn't doing it for you. It can't read your mind.

`abstract` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it. For some reason I thought that the automatic super call would work. Thanks!

Comment: @MataanP You should consider upvoting and/or accepting answers you find useful here.

Answer (score -1):

`RecurringEvent` needs to have a constructor that calls `super(int)` because the super constructor has a parameter. I'm pretty sure if the super constructor didnt have a parameter this would have worked.

Comment: And if the super constructor didn't have a parameter it *would* have worked, and there is no need to be merely 'pretty sure' about it when you can simply test it and see for yourself.